# web crawler in java. downloading web page issue

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, bufferedreader

I am trying to develop a small web crawler, which downloads the web pages and search for links in a specific section. But when i am running this code, links in "href" tag are getting shortened. like :

original link : "/kids-toys-action-figures-accessories/b/ref=toys_hp_catblock_actnfigs?ie=UTF8&node=165993011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_r=267646F4BB25430BAD0D&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1582921042&pf_rd_i=165793011"

turned into : "/kids-toys-action-figures-accessories/b?ie=UTF8&node=165993011"

can anybody help me please. below is my code :

```
package test;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.*;
public class myFirstWebCrawler {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String strTemp = "";
    String dir="d:/files/";
    String filename="hello.txt";
    String fullname=dir+filename;

    try {
        URL my_url = new URL("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_165993011_ex_n_1?rh=n%3A165793011&bbn=165793011&ie=UTF8&qid=1376550433");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(my_url.openStream(),"utf-8"));
        createdir(dir);
        while(null != (strTemp = br.readLine())){
            writetofile(fullname,strTemp);
        System.out.println(strTemp);

      }
        System.out.println("index of feature category : "  +  readfromfile(fullname,"Featured Categories"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void createdir(String dirname)
{ File d= new File(dirname);

  d.mkdirs();


}

public static void writetofile(String path, String bbyte)
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(path,true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
        bufferedWriter.write(bbyte);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {System.out.println("Error");}

}

public static int readfromfile(String path, String key)
{
    String dir="d:/files/";
    String filename="hello1.txt";
    String fullname=dir+filename;
    linksAndAt[] linksat=new linksAndAt[10];
    BufferedReader bf = null;
    try {
        bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String currentLine;
    int index =-1;
    try{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
    while((currentLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        index=currentLine.indexOf(key);
        if(index>0)
        { 
            writetofile(fullname,currentLine);
            int count=0;
            int lastIndex=0;
            while(lastIndex != -1)
            {
                lastIndex=currentLine.indexOf("href=\"",lastIndex);

                if(lastIndex != -1)
                {
                    lastIndex+="href=\"".length();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while(currentLine.charAt(lastIndex) != '\"')
                    {
                        sb.append(Character.toString(currentLine.charAt(lastIndex)));
                        lastIndex++;

                    }

                    count++;

                    System.out.println(sb);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n count : " + count);
            return index;
        }

    }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        f.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {try {
        bf.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }}
    return index;}
}
```

Comment: I believe you should go through the [Amazon API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) for conducting searches.

Comment: i just used it as an example.... any website you can use. its for learning purpose.

Comment: Well if you just want to learn about web scraping, I would suggest you use a site like [this](http://www.onelook.com/) to start off, considering it is much easier to parse the results.

Comment: i tried several sites. but in this site i found more scope to do things. this is just at random i got. i had it opened in my browser....btw do u have any answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This feels to me like a situation where the server app is responding differently to requests from your desktop browser and your Java-based crawler.  That could be because your browser is passing cookies in its requests which your Java-based crawler is not (such as session-persisting cookies), or it could be because your desktop browser passes a different User-Agent header than your crawler does, or it could be because other request headers are different between your desktop browser and your Java crawler.

When writing crawling apps, this is one of the biggest issues one runs into: it's easy to forget that the same URL requested by different clients won't always respond with the same code.  Not sure if that's what's happening to you here, but it's very common.